# Chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can we open chrome extension popup without clicking on icon button,Not open in a tab just like popup is opening in the press of icon just like how can we open it programmatically is there any way to open it , or how we can trigger a button press of keyboard through java script

Comment: You cannot open the popup window programmatically, there is no way.

Comment: how can we trigger a shortcut key like ctr l+m through java script on page load or on click on any button

Comment: You can add a shortcut by going into chrome://extensions click on the hamburger menu at the top right corner (the three stripes), click on Keyboard shortcuts and assign a shortcut for activating the extension. Although I don't think this is something you can enforce via your manifest.

Comment: Thank you sir that i know but i want to press that shortcut key as soon as page load programmatically how can we do that?